# Laravel Custom User Log Activity

Tags: laravel, access-log

Using Log Activity helper class I have done the part ,but the agent data is not correct or is showing demo data. When I am using chrome it shows same data even I use Firefox or another browser. How can I resolve the issue, I want when I am using chrome it gives me chrome, When I am using Firefox it shows me Firefox.
[image: Screenshot of the Problem]

```
public static function addToLog($subject)
{
    $log = [];
    $log['subject'] = $subject;
    $log['url'] = Request::fullUrl();
    $log['method'] = Request::method();
    $log['ip'] = Request::ip();
    $log['agent'] = Request::header('user-agent');
    $log['user_id'] = auth()->check() ? auth()->user()->id : 1;
    LogActivityModel::create($log);
}
```

My Log Activity Helper class is like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [package](https://github.com/hisorange/browser-detect) instead

```
composer require hisorange/browser-detect
```

In your code just call the Browser facade

```
use Browser;

// Determine the user's device type is simple as this:
Browser::isMobile();
Browser::isTablet();
Browser::isDesktop();

// Every wondered if it is a bot who loading Your page?
if (Browser::isBot()) {
    echo 'No need to wonder anymore!';
}

// Check for common vendors.
if (Browser::isFirefox() || Browser::isOpera()) {
    $response .= '<script src="firefox-fix.js"></script>';
}

// Sometime You may want to serve different content based on the OS.
if (Browser::isAndroid()) {
    $response .= '<a>Install our Android App!</a>';
} elseif (Browser::isMac() && Browser::isMobile()) {
    $response .= '<a>Install our iOS App!</a>';
}
```

You can even use it on your blade template

```
@mobile
    <p>This is the MOBILE template!</p>
    @include('your-mobile-template')
@endmobile

@tablet
    <p>This is the TABLET template!</p>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="tablet.css" title="Reduce the page size, load what the user need">
@endtablet

@desktop
    <p>This is the DESKTOP template!</p>
@enddesktop

{-- Every result key is supported --}
@browser('isBot')
    <p>Bots are identified too :)</p>
@endbrowser
```